# Dagger Application Component is not genereting

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm facing unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent
I've tried rebuild project and not worked.
Every solution that I found none worked.

This is my imports

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

// Dagger 2
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.4-3"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'

}
```

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528699/8770663) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269256/8770663) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605045/8770663).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Dagger dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

With the following:

```
implementation  'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

Then, build your project. It will generate your Dagger components, so they are available to import and use.
If they are still unavailable, check the compiler messages. Dagger won't generate components if you make a mistake with annotations and other dagger's things.

Answer (score 0):

click on Build->Make Project

enjoy!!